# Best way to manage bitmap storage in a long listview having big images?

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I have a long Listview(~300) having big images(~720 * 300) in each row. Now if I scroll to the end of the Listview, my hashmap(which stores bitmaps) holds 300 images. Due to which manytimes I get out of memory exception. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks for helping. Any code would be great!

Comment: you can use imageloader library or aquery library for loading your images

Comment: It will help me to download images easily, but how will it solve my problem?

Comment: they also store your image path in your phone and dispaly from that path. Also store all bitmap. If you store 300 image then that give memory exception.

Comment: True, they store images on external memory, but still it will keep image in some data structure, right? Only from there it displays images. And this data structure is on heap. And I have the same problem.

Comment: you should use lazy loading for getting more images.

Comment: I am using lazy loading but once I reach end of the list scrolling slowly, I will be having all the images. Which would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Picasso helps you download the pictures, resize them if needed, and cache them. It also handles ListView specific problems, like freeing memory to ensure smooth scrolling.

Comment: I really recommend using Picasso. It's a lightweight library and full of features, including the one you are seeking here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix that you need to make the heap bigger in the Android Manifest,
also lazy loading if your loading them online and you have to reuse cells

Comment: I dont want to keep 300 at a time, I want to keep may 2 or 3 times of page size (items displayed on a page). Any leads to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: On loading them, you can use like most apps the load more on scroll to bottom of the image list , and reuse the cells used before.http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter.html ( This is a tutorial for the endless adapter)

Comment: Cells are automatically resused in case of listview. Its not about cell, its about bitmap for each cell. Which will be different for different cells and cant be reused

Comment: they are automatically reused but not properly , you can see that if you add a row the memory goes up. Supposedly cell reuse should not take more memory but replace the existing content. Therefore the application can load infinite images.

Comment: @VipulJ, Picasso does exactly this, it has a LRU cache for bitmaps, limited in size (about 1/7 of the available memory). It takes care of recycling the bitmaps when the cache is filled.